# Mostrar información de excepción SQLException

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8.2

Quiero mostrar la información de la excepción lanzada por la base de datos, tal cuál la muestra mi compilador por consola:

> "Duplicate entry '39457111' for key 'dni'".

Por ejemplo al ingresar una entrada duplicada.

```
try{
//codigo
}
catch(SQLException ex){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
}
```

Pero me da error de compilación en la linea del `catch` diciéndome:

> exception SQLException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es una buena práctica mostrar el error tal cuál es lanzado, en lugar de eso deberías de mostrar un mensaje personalizado, puedes crear una exepción personalizada y en caso de que ocurra una excepción como la de "DataIntegrityViolationException"(la cuál no creo que sea correcto utilizarla con la finalidad de que se intente duplicar un registro debido a que se puede lanzar por otras cosas) entonces loguear esa excepción, algo parecido a esto:

```
try{
if(existeRegistro("registro1")){
  throw new RegistroDuplicadoException("El registro ya se encuentra registrado");
//El resto de tu código
}
catch(RegistroDuplicadoException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
catch(SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e){
    LOG.error("Error con base de datos", e);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ha ocurrido un error de bd, contacte a su administrador");
}
```

Comment: Si, entiendo que es mejor personalizar el mensaje, lo que vengo haciendo (sé que no está bien, pero tendré que sacrificar esos detalles jaj) es mostrar  primero el mensaje personalizado (para el usuario) y luego `\n` la información del error (para mi en el caso que un día se caiga el programa y el cliente me llame jaj). Igualmente solo hay dos posibilidades que lance excepción la DB: entrada duplicada en campo `dni` y `telefono`, por que controlo todo con el programa. Voy a probar tu solución que parece que es la que mejor se adapta

Comment: Y cuando cree mi clase `RegistroDuplicadoException` la extiendo de `Exception`?

Comment: Exactamente, también puedes manejar códigos de error, por si el mensaje no es lo suficientemente claro para tu usuario lo pueda revisar de un catálogo o algo parecido, si hay que extender de exception, algo así:

public class RegistroDuplicadoException  extends Exception {
 public RegistroDuplicadoException (String message) {
  super(message);
 }
}


Si te parece que es la respuesta puedes marcarla como respuesta

Comment: esta saliendo todo perfecto pero me queda el último `catch` de `DataIntegrityViolationException`, le doy `alt`+`enter` y no me aparece la opción de importar esa clase

Comment: disculpa, olvidé que no es Spring... `DataIntegrityViolationException` es para spring, ya edité la respuesta... la que debes utilizar es es `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` y puedes encontrar más información de esta en:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.html

Comment: @FernandoAguilar Si propones primero evaluar si el registro existe, lanzar una  excepción estaría de más, ya que es un comportamiento controlado y la excepción solo agregaría código innecesario.

Comment: @crrlos si, me parecía, pero igual me sirvió para aprender a crear excepciones personalizadas. Ahora quiero usar ese `catch(SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException sqlInteg)` en otra parte de mi programa para justamente no controlar nada, que lance la excepción `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` pero me obliga a dispara la excepción dentro del `try`. Cómo hago para que sea lanzada automáticamente cuando se produce el error de sql

Comment: Bueno ya lo solucioné. La clase no es `SQLException` ni `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`, la clase es `ConstraintViolationException`, será por que uso `Hibernate`, debí indicarlo. Y el método para mostrar información del error es `objeto.getCause().getMessage()`

Comment: Que bien que lo solucionaras!... y sí creo que debemos proporcionar/pedir más detalles para obtener mejores resultados

Answer (score 0):

La clase `SQLException` hereda un método [`getMessage()` de `Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage()), puedes usar ese método para mostrar el mensaje de error, por ejemplo:

```
try{
//codigo
}
catch(SQLException ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: pero por qué no me compila? Me dice `exception SQLException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement`, o sea me pide que la lance en el `try`, pero yo no quiero evaluar cuando tiene que lanzarse, sino que se lance automáticamente cuando se produzca

Comment: El problema es que el código que está dentro de tu try no lanza una excepción de tipo SQLException. Es lo que el mensaje de error dice literalmente: SQLException nunca es lanzada en el cuerpo del bloque try correspondiente.